# Vote count on mobile web version

Tags: feature-request, mobile

I just noticed that I am not able to see the vote counts on the mobile verstion of U&L SE, while I can do so in the normal web version. Am I missing some otherwise obvious operations, settings etc., or is it a feature to be added?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean the +N and -Y you see when clicking on the score? That doesn't work on mobile AFAIK, no.

Comment: In a mobile browser or the app? Safari and the app work for me.

Comment: The former. I am using Chrome on Android (may provide the detailed UA information if needed)

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296739/307535

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show the number of up-votes and down-votes on the mobile site theme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108769/show-the-number-of-up-votes-and-down-votes-on-the-mobile-site-theme)

Comment: Can you close meta Q’s cross-site??

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes it is a duplicate. I wanted to close it as a duplicate but was told that a duplicate should be on U&L meta rather than meta. I don't know how to flsg it the way you do.